# opensearch authentication with opensearch-py on aws lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam, opensearch

I am trying to connect to AWS OpenSearch domain from AWS Lambda using the opensearch python client (development purposes, non production).

I was trying the following:

```py
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch
import boto3
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
import os
import config
my_region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
service = 'es' # still es???
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, my_region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
openSearch_endpoint = config.openSearch_endpoint

# sth wrong here:
openSearch_client = OpenSearch(hosts = [openSearch_endpoint], auth = awsauth)
```

as per the following blogs:

- https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/indexing-metadata-in-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda-and-python/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/opensearch-service/latest/developerguide/search-example.html

but it does not work (it does not want to authenticate, `"errorMessage":"AuthorizationException(403, '')"` . However if I don't use the python client but simply go through `requests` instead:

```py
import requests
host = config.openSearch_endpoint
url = host + '/' +'_cat/indices?v'
# this one works:
r = requests.get(url, auth=awsauth)
```

, my lambda function does communicate with the OpenSearch domain.

I consulted the `OpenSearch()` documentation but it is not clear to me how its parameters map to `boto3` session credentials, and/or to `AWS4Auth`. So what should this line

```
openSearch_client = OpenSearch(hosts = [openSearch_endpoint], auth = awsauth)
```

be?

Answer (score 6):

actually managed to find the solution a couple of hours later:

```py
from opensearchpy import OpenSearch, RequestsHttpConnection
my_region = os.environ['AWS_REGION']
service = 'es' # still es?
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key, credentials.secret_key, my_region, service, session_token=credentials.token)
host = config.openSearch_endpoint

openSearch_client = OpenSearch(
        hosts=[openSearch_endpoint],
        http_auth = awsauth,
        use_ssl = True,
        verify_certs = True,
        ssl_assert_hostname = False,
        ssl_show_warn = False,
        connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
        )
```

Comment: This code is still wrong. You are not specifiying the port: 443

Answer (score 0):

OpenSearch Service requires port 443 for incoming requests therefore you need to add a new Inbound Rule under Security Group attached to your OpenSearch Service domain.

Try the rule:

- Type: HTTPS
- Protocol: TCP
- Port range: 443
- Source: 0.0.0.0/0 (Anywhere-IPv4)

Additionally, you should have a Resource-based policy for your Lambda function to perform requests to your OpenSearch Service domain.

Comment: At my case the security group with source 0.0.0.0/0 was the final step to complete the access from lambda to Opensearch, however is not a good practice. Instead you can check in Network Interfaces looking for the eni-xxxxx created by lambda, then copy the IPs and add to the OpenSearch security group to restrict the access just for the lambda